# Getter returning null when testing get methods

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sqlite, getter

I am trying to get data from my database to show on a listview. The problem I am having is it seems the getters are not working properly. When I test what they are returning, it comes back null.

Any insight would be appreciated as I am lost here. Thanks in advance.

Here is where I initialise the class:

```
    public ArrayList<GameStats> getAllData() {
    ArrayList<GameStats> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM savedGamesTable", null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String lName = cursor.getString(1);
        int lScore = cursor.getInt(2);
        String rName = cursor.getString(3);
        int rScore = cursor.getInt(4);
        String notes = cursor.getString(5);

        GameStats gameStats = new GameStats(id, lName, lScore, rName, rScore, notes);
        arrayList.add(gameStats);

    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Here is where I am trying to use the getters:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_saved_games, null);
        TextView lName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lName);
        TextView lScore = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lScore);
        TextView rName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rName);
        TextView rScore = convertView.findViewById(R.id.rScore);
        TextView notes = convertView.findViewById(R.id.notes);

    GameStats gameStats = arrayList.get(position);
    testVar = gameStats.getlName();
    Log.d("MyAdaptor","gameStats = " + var);
    lName.setText(gameStats.getlName());
    lScore.setText(String.valueOf(gameStats.getlScore()));
    rName.setText(gameStats.getrName());
    rScore.setText(String.valueOf(gameStats.getrScore()));
    notes.setText(gameStats.getNotes());
    return convertView;
}
```

Here is the model class:

```
public class GameStats {
int id, lScore, rScore;
String lName, rName, notes;

public GameStats(int id, String lName, int lScore, String rName, int rScore, String notes) {

}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getlScore() {
    return lScore;
}

public void setlScore(int lScore) {
    this.lScore = lScore;
}

public int getrScore() {
    return rScore;
}

public void setrScore(int rScore) {
    this.rScore = rScore;
}

public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}

public void setlName(String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}

public String getrName() {
    return rName;
}

public void setrName(String rName) {
    this.rName = rName;
}

public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

public void setNotes(String notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}
```

}

and here is where I am calling the methods:

```
public class SavedGameScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv1;
ArrayList<GameStats> arrayList;
MyAdaptor myAdaptor;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_game_screen);
    lv1 = findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    loadData();
}

private void loadData() {
    arrayList = databaseHelper.getAllData();
    myAdaptor = new MyAdaptor(this, arrayList);
    lv1.setAdapter(myAdaptor);
    myAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: I see that your `GameStats` parameterized constructor  is empty and you are not setting class fields with the parameters you are passing. If this is the case then obviously all getters will return default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the constructor as below and see if that works,

```
public GameStats(int id, String lName, int lScore, String rName, int rScore, String notes) {
    this.id = id;
    this.lName = IName;
    this.lScore = IScore;
    this.rName = rName;
    this.rScore = rScore;
    this.notes = notes;
    }
```

Comment: Something so simple.. thanks for the quick response, data is showing on the list view now.

Answer (score 1):

In your model class initialize the variables using constrtuctor. I guess that is the problem. Since you are not initializing the model class properties, it the getters will return "null" or any garbage value

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the values to the model constructor but you are not assigning it to the model variables. You need to change the code as below,

```
public GameStats(int id, String lName, int lScore, String rName, int rScore, String notes) {
    this.id = id;
    this.lName = IName;
    this.lScore = IScore;
    this.rName = rName;
    this.rScore = rScore;
    this.notes = notes;
    }
```

Else initialise each variable through `setter()` method.